# Explaination for the following media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Please explain me how the following responsive media query works.

```
  @media not screen,screen and(max-width:400px)
{
nav,ad{
       display:none;
       }
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
}
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Please format your code. Then just read any tutorial on media queries.

Answer (score 1):

`not screen` means it will apply to media types that arent screens (Print etc.)

`screen and(max-width:400px)` means it will apply to all media types using a screen where window width is `400px` or lower.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the CSS as the "ad" tag does not exist. Are you sure its not

```
nav.ad {
```

Please check and correct that error first.

```
nav.ad{
   display:none;
   }
```

The above CSS will **hide** the element with the class="ad" when the display screen width is 1px to 400px
and

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
}
```

The above CSS will inherit the URL/href font-color from the parent ID/tag

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. The OP is asking for an explanation of the media query `@media not screen,screen and(max-width:400px)`. And in respect to the `ad` tag, it is most likely a [custom HTML element](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) (see also [How to Create Custom HTML Elements](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-custom-html-elements-2))

Comment: true, but considering "not screen,screen" is not a valid media feature, also presumed the error lay with the CSS selector. either way, it'll render only the "screen" selector for the pre-defined width. Also, can contradictory selectors be present together like "not screen, screen" ?

Comment: @masmrdrr those are comma separated. Does that not mean it is for "not screen" and "screen" so he could have used "all" instead.

Comment: @Gezzasa - `all` could *not* be used in this case. The OP's query basically says "anything that is not screen, and screens with max-width ....". Changing to `all` would mean that all screens are targeted regardless of width - making the second selector redundant

Comment: "not screen,screen" is two entirely separate and valid media queries. They are neither selectors nor media features. But just like selectors, you can have two separate media queries in the same rule and they will still match according to their own criteria. Whether that creates a redundancy is a separate matter. In this particular case, the (max-width:400px) expression only applies to the screen media query, so distinguishes it from the not screen media query.